How long had Adam and Eve been a couple before the fall
How long did it take for a couple who were perfect to have a child? Why Adam and Eve never got pregnant before the fall?

the second question may have different answers depending on which denomination you ask

@depperm, there could have been many decades before the fall. Can we say for sure that they didn't have unrecorded children before that (e.g. Cain's wife)?

@RayButterworth that could be the case (I didn't say they weren't), in which case this question is opinion based as there is no record

Seth was born when Adam was 130 years old. Cain and Abel were born some time before that. Beyond that... we don't know.

@Matthew  If (as some suggest) a 'day' is 24 hours, then by the time the sun was setting (the cool of the day) the woman had already been deceived and the man had already transgressed on the first day of their existence,

@NigelJ, why do you assume Genesis 3 is happening on Day 6 of Creation? I don't see any strong reason to believe "the day" in 3:8 means Creation Day 6, as opposed to "cool of the day" simply being an expression meaning "evening" (or maybe "morning"!) without indicating a specific day. Especially as my footnote says "wind of the day", which suggests a thing, not a time.

Cain and Abel were probably in the garden. Adam and Eve were possibly together for 500 years, or half of a biblical day before the fall.
